# Gurobi error: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'gurobipy.QuadExpr

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, gurobi, quadratic-programming

I have the following formulation that I need to implement using Gurobi for optimization: [See here for formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjjOr.png)

And here is the code using the Gurobi Python API:

```
from gurobipy import *

m=Model()
# Create variables
alphak = m.addVars(S, B, b, a, vtype=GRB.BINARY,name="alphak")

# Set objective
obj1=quicksum(quicksum(quicksum(int((quicksum(alphak[s,B0,f,t]*alphak[s,k,f,t] for k in B0)/len(B0)) for t in range(a)) for f in range(b)) for s in S)

m.setObjective(obj1, GRB.MAXIMIZE)

# Optimize model
m.optimize()
```

The problem arises in the application of int() on the quicksum. This is the error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'gurobipy.QuadExpr
```

Same thing of the division.

Anyone who could help me resolve this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Gurobi does not understand int(), ceiling() or floor() functions. However, you can model your way around this quite easily.

Say we want to model `y = floor(x)`. Then you can write:

```
 y <= x
 y >= x - 0.999999
 y integer
```

Comment: As you can see the int() is in the middle of formula. I have reused loops instead of quicksums and applied ur proposition, but it doesn't work , with error 'gurobiby.QuadExpr' object is not iterable... Any hint!

Comment: `int() is in the middle of formula`. The obvious approach is to add some auxiliary variables and equations.